# kafka IllegalStateError: Producer is closed forcefully

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have the following code :

```
 __kafka_client = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'))
 for(msg in messages):    
    __kafka_client.send('TOPIC', dumps(msg)).add_callback(on_kafka_send_success).add_errback(on_kafka_send_error)

def on_kafka_send_success(record_metadata):
    print(record_metadata.topic)
def on_kafka_send_error(excp):
   kafa_error_message  = "Error while sending kafka message :"+str(excp);
   raise Exception(excp)
```

`
I am getting following error when loop ends:

```
Error while sending kafka message :IllegalStateError: Producer is closed forcefully.
NoneType: None
```

How can I avoid/fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This issue reproduces for me when closing the client process right after calling the produce/send method. Apparently, the message buffer is not necessarily flushed before the interpreter is done running the send() call.
like in Bhuneshwer's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940821/12912120),
you can use flush() in order to flush the message buffer before terminating the process or if you don't end the process right away, the message will be sent soon enough (this "soon enough" can be configured by queue.buffering.max.ms).

please note that flush() blocks until the buffer flush is complete thus using flush after each produce call is equivalent to implementing a synchronous flow and may hinder performance.

please refer to this answer by the confluent-kafka guys for more info:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/137#issuecomment-282427382

Answer (score 1):

Solved using

```
__kafka_client = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'))
 for(msg in messages):    
    __kafka_client.send('TOPIC', dumps(msg)).add_callback(on_kafka_send_success).add_errback(on_kafka_send_error)

__kafka_clinet.flush()
```